# Trouble Connecting to MongoDB with Java Async Client

Tags: java, mongodb

I've used MongoDB with Python for a while now, and I've recently tried it with Java and i  keep getting the same error.

Here is my code (with username and password replaced):

```
public class MongoClientConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://<username>:<password>@cluster0.bog1c.mongodb.net/db?w=majority");
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
        MongoCollection<Document> accounts = database.getCollection("accounts");
        Document doc = new Document("name", new String[]{"John", "Smith"})
            .append("age", 35)
            .append("favorite_color", "blue");
        accounts.insertOne(doc, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Inserted!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This was taken directly from [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/getting-started/quick-tour/) tutorial.

Here is the output:

```
Jan 15, 2022 3:17:53 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[cluster0.bog1c.mongodb.net:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Jan 15, 2022 3:17:53 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by PrimaryServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=cluster0.bog1c.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am able to connect to the database using Mongosh. The string given on the `cloud.mongodb.com` site begins with `mongodb+srv://`, however it gives me the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri needs to start with mongodb://`

That is why I am using only `mongodb://`.

I am running the code on Intellij IDEA in Windows.

Any ideas for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933821/cant-connect-to-local-mongodb-from-java/31935871 which roughly describes the same problem and possible code change to wait for a connection - since I can't see any timeouts or error messages from your output.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I have decided against MongoDB entirely. For my purposes, it is unnecessary. I used JSON.simple and I wrote a simple class to deal with a local database. It’s much faster than MongoDB because it’s local and it’s running on a server that I already intended to use.